# Cassandra DB (with PHP and Android application access)

Tags: php, mobile, cassandra, social-networking

I am new with NoSQL databases (I have always working with Oracle and MySql databases), but now I am just starting to develop a mobil/web application (a mobile oriented social network), but now I have a silly, but very big doubt:

Should I set up a Cassandra database (like you implement a MySQL tables, relations, etc)

and...

develop a PHP functionality web (social network will also have a web access), and from that Php web develop the android/iphone client application (it will only replicate web functionalities).

I am very confused in the approach I should follow. Could anyone give me an advice???

(I have said Php because is a very optimal web language with server support (Java and related hostings are more expensive, etc but that is not the debate, even I also accept advice in this point if relevant).

Thank you everybody so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create 1 keyspace which is similar to schema in DBMS and then you can create columnfamily which is similar to table in DBMS.

their is nothing like foreign key in cassandra, so you have to create you columnfamily structure in a way that only one table will going to satisfied all your requirement(individual columnfamily).

and facebook is using cassandra and php so you have to search how can you do similar for your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know Facebook uses PHP + Cassandra, but my main doubt is how to set up this architecture into a mobile app.

Comment: i am also not aware of it, u have to do some re-search on google for this.